# RestSharp JsonDeserializer list object

Tags: c#, restsharp, json-deserialization

I want to deserialize a JSON with array using RestSharp deserialize.

```
public class details
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string tran_id { get; set; }
    public string tran_type { get; set; }
    public string tran_status { get; set; }
    public string expiry_date_time { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
}
```

My JSON as below:

```
{
"details": [
    {
        "id": "ebca66079b44",
        "tran_id": "c9b1bce025f5",
        "tran_type": "A",
        "tran_status": "B",
        "expiry_date_time": "2018-11-26T06:33:04+00:00",
        "number": "12345678ABC"
    },
    {
        "id": "ebca66079b44",7c2445c8-a5ba-4ad2-a38e-3ea682c60edf",
        "tran_id": "3ea682c60edf",
        "tran_type": "A",
        "tran_status": "B",
        "expiry_date_time": "2018-11-26T06:26:28+00:00",
        "number": "22345678ABC"
    },
    {
        "id": "ebca66079b44",
        "tran_id": "e40c45817985",
        "tran_type": "A",
        "tran_status": "B",
        "expiry_date_time": "2018-11-26T06:26:06+00:00",
        "number": "32345678ABC"
    }
]
}
```

And my code is:

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
//Deserialize Json
return new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<List<details>>(response);
```

I am able to get 'details', but not the list inside the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an object contain your JSON array data, because the outermost layer is an object instead of an array.

```
public class JsonModel
{
    public List<Detail> details { get; set; }
}


public class Detail
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string tran_id { get; set; }
    public string tran_type { get; set; }
    public string tran_status { get; set; }
    public string expiry_date_time { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
}
```

use like this.

```
new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<JsonModel>(response);
```

**Note**

There is a json data might throw an error  from `"ebca66079b44",7c2445c8-a5ba-4ad2-a38e-3ea682c60edf",` data.

There is two way can create model easily.

- You can use Web Essentials in Visual Studio, use Edit > Paste special > paste JSON as a class, you can easier to know the relation between Json and model.
- If you can't use Web Essentials you can instead of use https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp online JSON to Model class.

You can try to use those models to carry your JSON Format.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Response.Data`

here my sample code

```
        public T Execute<T>(RestRequest request, HttpStatusCode expectedResponseCode) where T : new()
    {
        // Won't throw exception.
        var response = _client.Execute<T>(request);

        return response.Data;
    }


    public List<Project> GetProjects()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest()
        {
            Resource = ResourceUrls.Project(),
            RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
            Method = Method.GET
        };

        return Execute<List<Project>>(request, HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```